# List information disappearing

Tags: c#

THIS IS HOMEWORK: I have a program that consists of two winforms and three classes.  The program does the work it is supposed to do for the main form and displays it appropriately onto the textbox of the main form.  In addition to displaying the information, it is also saved to a string list.  The data consists of order information.

The string list passes that information along to a method in another class and stores it in a list as it is supposed to do.  After this is done, I press a button which opens up another form.  In this form I enter an order number.  What is supposed to happen is that a method compares the order number entered with the row number of the list and return that information, whereupon it is displayed in the textbox of the second form.

That is what is supposed to happen.  Instead, when it is time to compare the order number with the row number of the list, the list data is gone and I cannot figure out why.  Here is my code that pertains:

```
 private void btnPaymentButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        amountPaid = double.Parse(this.txtAmountPaid.Text);
        orderObject.GetChangeDue(orderObject.TotalAmountDue, amountPaid);                   

        this.txtNumberOfPizzaOrdered.Clear();
        this.txtNumberOfCokesOrdered.Clear();
        this.txtAmountDue.Clear();
        this.txtAmountPaid.Clear();
        this.lblYourOrder.Visible = true;
        this.rtxtYourOrder.Visible = true;
        this.rtxtYourOrder.Text = orderObject.OrderSummary(amountPaid);

        //storeOrderObject = new DailySummary(orderObject.OrderSummary(amountPaid));

        storeOrderObject = new DailySummary(this.rtxtYourOrder.Text);           
    }     

private void btnDailySummary_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DailySummaryForm form = new DailySummaryForm();
       // this.Visible = false;
        form.Show();
    }

........

public class DailySummary
{
    //declare variables
    int numberOfCokes = 0,
        numberOfPizzas = 0,
        totalOfCokes = 0,
        totalOfPizzas = 0,            
        orderNumberRequest = 0;        

    string orderFromForm1 = "",
           getAllTheOrders = "",
           getAnOrder = "";

    List<string> pizzaOrderList = new List<string>();

    public DailySummary(string orderForm)
    {
        orderFromForm1 = orderForm;
        StoreOrder(orderFromForm1);
    }

    public DailySummary(int orderRequest)
    {
        orderNumberRequest = orderRequest;
        GetOrder(OrderNumberRequest);
    }

public int OrderNumberRequest
    {
        get
        {
            return this.orderNumberRequest;
        }
    }        

//store order
    public void StoreOrder(string orderFromForm1)
    {
        pizzaOrderList.Add(orderFromForm1);
    }

    //get the order
    public string GetOrder(int OrderNumberRequest)
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < pizzaOrderList.Count; row++)
        {
            if (row == (OrderNumberRequest - 1))
            {
                getAnOrder = pizzaOrderList[row];
            }
        }
        return getAnOrder;
    }

........

public partial class DailySummaryForm : Form
{
    int orderNumberRequest = 0;
    //instantiate a from object
    OrderForm formObject;
    DailySummary summaryObject;

    public DailySummaryForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnOrderNumberButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        orderNumberRequest = int.Parse(this.txtOrderNumber.Text);
        summaryObject = new DailySummary(orderNumberRequest);

        this.rtxtDisplayOutput.Visible = true;
        this.rtxtDisplayOutput.Text = summaryObject.GetAnOrder;
    }
```

Comment: It is appreciated when you mention that it is homework.

Comment: I was unaware of this.  I have made the appropriate edit

Comment: would be easier to help if you showed a picture..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your method btnPaymentButton_Click you create an instance of the DailySummary class, then later on when your in the DailySummaryForm you create a new instance of the DailySummary Class.

These instances are separate and therefore do not share the same values.

As your not persisting values to the DB you'll probably want to:

1. look into making your DailySummary [Static](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (which will make it accessable throughout your
   winform application). (It's not typically good practice to have too many global (static) variables hanging around, but without a persistence engine where you can store your Daily Summary you need a common place to look it up.
2. Pass the initialized instance of the DailySummary class to your DailySummaryForm. (The DailySummaryForm could expose a public property.  The drawback of this method is if your switching between both forms and each form modified your summary class, your going to constantly have to pass it back and forth between the forms.

Comment: In the method btnPaymentButton_Click I had to create an instance of the DailySummary class so that I could use the button to call up the DailySummary form.  In the DailySummaryForm I needed to create a new instance in order to pass the orderNumber to the DailySummary class.  How would I do that so that the instances are the same?

Comment: can instances be passed like variables and lists?

Comment: If you make your DailySummary class static (you will also need to make the properties static as well), you wont need to create an instance of it in either of the classes.  you will just be able to call DailySummary.GetAnOrder.  By flagging an object as static it gets initialized when the application is started.  If it's a public object, then you can reference it from anywhere inside your application without having to initialize it.

Comment: Yes instances can be passed like variables and lists. (option 2).  Keep in mind, if you choose to make DailySummary static, your not going to need to create an instance of it or pass it around, it's available globally.  (Which can bring up some race conditions, however that's probably a future topic that you don't need to worry about now).

Comment: OK. I still get confused about the whole static/instance issue. but I think I got it.  I will make the appropriate changes and take it from there.  Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Think of it this way.  If you declare a static class, then it gets initialized once when the application starts up.  When you reference it in your code you don't have to initialize it because that's already done for you.  If the class isn't static it's scope is limited.  The class/form that initialized the local variable can reference it's values, however if you want to share those values you need to share your local instance with the other class.  Hope that's a little clearer and good luck with your assignment.

Comment: I have made everything static and cleaned everything up.  However, now that I cannot have an instance of DailySummary, how do I call up the form from my main form from within the btnDailySummary_Click event handler?  when I type "DailySummary." intellisense gives a bunch of options that do not apply.

Answer (score 0):

*DailySummaryForm* is creating a new instance of

> DailySummary.

and that is why it is empty.